# Does $\partial_t u(x,t) - \partial_x u(x,t) = 0$ have a non-trivial solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Consider the linear PDE $$\partial_t u(x,t) - \partial_x u(x,t) = 0$$ on the domain $$\Omega=\{(x,t)\;\;|\;\;0\leq x \leq 1,\;0\leq t \leq T\}$$
with boundary conditions $$u(0,t)=u(1,t)=c$$ and the initial condition $$u(x,0)=u_0(x).$$

This is a special case of the [advection-diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation) or the heat equation with additional terms. In trying to solve this PDE using separation of variables and specifying $u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$, I find only the trivial solution. In trying to use Fourier methods to solve the more general problem \begin{align}\partial_{t} u(x,t)&=k\,\partial_{xx}u(x,t)+A\,\partial_x u(x,t)+B\,u(x,t)\\u(0,t)&=u(L,t)=0\\u(x,0)&=u_0(x)\end{align}
on the domain $$\Omega=\{(x,t)\;\;|\;\;0\leq x \leq L,\;0\leq t \leq T\},$$ I find the solution to be $$u(x,t)=e^{-\frac{A}{2k}x+(-\frac{A^{2}}{4k}+B)t}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)e^{-n^{2}\pi^{2}kt/L^{2}}$$where$$
b_{n}=\int_{0}^{L}e^{\frac{A}{2k}\xi}f(\xi)\,sin\left(\frac{n\pi\xi}{L}\right)\,d\xi$$
and $f(x)=u(x,0)$ (see P. 52 of O'Neil, *Beginning Partial Differential Equations*, 3rd Edition, Wiley (2014)). However, for the case of $k=B=0$, the Fourier coefficients blow up.

**Does this equation have a non-trivial solution?**

Comment: As in Euler's and other's early discussion of the wave equation, your equation has solutions $u(x,t)=f(x+t)$ for any distribution $f$. I didn't try imposing your boundary conditions to see what they'd say...

Comment: Regards @nowonka . As far as i know, the solution for $u_{t} = u_{x}$ does not have anything to do with the solution for $u_{tt} = ku_{xx} + Au_{t} + Bu$. The first one is the advection (or translation equation). May I ask why do you connect with the second equation? Thanks

Comment: @Arief I made two typos, sorry. The equation is $\partial_{t} u(x,t)=k\,\partial_{xx}u(x,t)+A\,\partial_x u(x,t)+B\,u(x,t)$. If I found the general solution and then set $k=B=0$, $A=1$, I would have the general solution to $u_t=u_x$.

Comment: @nowonka What more information about $f(\xi)$? we still don't know how $f$ affects the coefficient..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the boundary conditions, there is only the trivial solution, $u\equiv c$ if $T\ge 1$. However, for $T<1$, non-trivial solutions are possible. This can be seen by using the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics):

Here, the characteristics are easily found, they are the lines parametrized by $s\mapsto (-s, s)$, along these lines the solution of your PDE has to be constant. By ignoring the particular choice of $T$ and the boundary condition at $x=0$, we get the unique solution:
$$u(x,t) = \begin{cases}u_0(x+t),\quad &\text{for }0<x<1-t, \\
c,\quad &\text{for }0<x\ge 1-t   \end{cases}.$$
Now we need to also take the B.C. at $x = 0$ into account, which is fulfilled iff (according to the above representation of $u$) $c = u(0,t) = u_0(t)$ for $t<T$. If $u_0$ doesn't fulfill this condition, there is no solution to the problem at all.
If $T\ge 1$, this means that $u_0 \equiv c$ is necessary, and $u\equiv c$ is the only solution, which is trivial.
If $T<1$, we are free to choose $u_0(x)\neq c$ for $1>x>T$, without conflicting the left boundary condition.

Answer (score 3):

For your first equation, the characteristics are given by $dx/dt = -1$. So on $t$-vs-$x$ plane, they "travel" backwards with slope 1.

Thus, if there exists $x \in (0,1)$ such that $u_0(x) \neq c$, then there will be a discontinuity at some $t$ and at $x = 0$. As I understand it, these are sometimes called weak solutions (my terminology might be wrong here).

If you strictly want continuous solutions, then there is only the trivial solution.

Comment: Some form of continuity still needs to be imposed, otherwise pointwise boundary conditions are not meaningful any more. Typically, continuity along characteristics (unless they intersect) is assumed for weak solutions of first order hyperbolic equations.

Comment: @DominikS Thanks for pointing it out. I assumed that B.C.'s are always imposed. So for continuity along the characteristics, it should suffice that $u_0(x)$ be piecewise continuous.

Comment: Yes, or even just integrability - such equations usually have a quite physical interpretation (e.g. mass transport, ...), a weak formulation is usually some integrated version. In my experience, imposing b.c.s  that might conflict with $u_0$ are unusual. The b.c. is usually rather used as an init. cond. for characteristics, such that the solution can be constructed on the entire domain.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U(x,t)$ and $V(x,t)$ be any two solutions to the PDE $u_{t} - u_{x} = 0$. If $U(x,t)$ and $V(x,t)$ have different initial and boundary conditions, then of course the solution would be different also. So assume the initial and boundary conditions are the same.

Both are solutions, so 
$$ U_{t} - U_{x} = 0 , \:\:\:\:\: V_{t} - V_{x} = 0$$
Now let $W(x,t) = U(x,t) - V(x,t)$, we get
$$ W_{t}  - W_{x} = (U_{t} - V_{t}) - (U_{x} - V_{x}) = 0 $$
so $W(x,t)$ is also a solution.

Now notice that $$ W(x,0) = U(x,0) - V(x,0) = 0 $$, and the same applies at the boundaries.

Since there is no disturbances, source, or sink, then $W(x,t)$ will not have any change. So $W(x,t) = 0$ for $0<x<L$, $t>0$. Which means $U(x,t) = V(x,t)$.

But another way, you may also use your Fourier method result to prove that :
$$ W(x,0) = 0 \:\:\: \implies \:\:\: b_{n} = 0 $$
then see what this means.

Hope this helps, thanks.